# Zurb Foundation 3 + RequireJS: plugins loading problems

Tags: requirejs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to load Zurb Foundation 3 with RequireJS. Here's my configuration section:

```
require.config({
    paths:
    {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        'foundation': 'libs/foundation/foundation.min',
        'foundation-init': 'libs/foundation/app'
    },
    shim:
    {
        'foundation': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-init': {
            deps: ['foundation']
        }
    }
});
```

Then, always in the main file, I include Foundation:

```
require(['foundation-init']);
```

The problem is that, for example, the top-bar doesn't expand (jquery animation) like it should do (see here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php#topbarEx). It's like the Foundation jQuery plugins are not correctly loaded. As I read, that's the reason why in the Foundation doc **the scripts are loaded at the end of the body**. But, obviously, with RequireJS it's a little more complex. I've temporarily fixed like suggested in the RequireJS doc ("Loading Code After Page Load" section), setting a timeout like that:

```
setTimeout(function() { require(['foundation-init']); }, 500);
```

I don't think it's a good solution. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, the reason is probably that I have an empty body in my page, which is then modified by the Backbone router through views. So, the jQuery events actions like animations are not correctly binded because when the document.ready event tryes to make them, the body is still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the problem with a **little hack**!

As I supposed, *the problem was that the new DOM section after the view rendering with Backbone, has Foundation jQuery events not binded.*

My solution is **to create a new plugin function `.foundation()`, which has to be applied to a section of the DOM for initializing Foundation on it**. So, I modified the file `app.js` of the Foundation package from:

```
;(function ($, window, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  var $doc = $(document),
      Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.foundationAlerts           ? $doc.foundationAlerts() : null;
    $.fn.foundationButtons          ? $doc.foundationButtons() : null;
    $.fn.foundationAccordion        ? $doc.foundationAccordion() : null;
    $.fn.foundationNavigation       ? $doc.foundationNavigation() : null;
    $.fn.foundationTopBar           ? $doc.foundationTopBar() : null;
    $.fn.foundationCustomForms      ? $doc.foundationCustomForms() : null;
    $.fn.foundationMediaQueryViewer ? $doc.foundationMediaQueryViewer() : null;
    $.fn.foundationTabs             ? $doc.foundationTabs({callback : $.foundation.customForms.appendCustomMarkup}) : null;
    $.fn.foundationTooltips         ? $doc.foundationTooltips() : null;
    $.fn.foundationMagellan         ? $doc.foundationMagellan() : null;
    $.fn.foundationClearing         ? $doc.foundationClearing() : null;

    $.fn.placeholder                ? $('input, textarea').placeholder() : null;
  });

  // UNCOMMENT THE LINE YOU WANT BELOW IF YOU WANT IE8 SUPPORT AND ARE USING .block-grids
  // $('.block-grid.two-up>li:nth-child(2n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.three-up>li:nth-child(3n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.four-up>li:nth-child(4n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.five-up>li:nth-child(5n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});

  // Hide address bar on mobile devices (except if #hash present, so we don't mess up deep linking).
  if (Modernizr.touch && !window.location.hash) {
    $(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
      }, 0);
    });
  }

})(jQuery, this);
```

to:

```
;(function ($, window, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  $.fn.foundation = function () {
    $.fn.foundationAlerts           ? $(this).foundationAlerts() : null;
    $.fn.foundationButtons          ? $(this).foundationButtons() : null;
    $.fn.foundationAccordion        ? $(this).foundationAccordion() : null;
    $.fn.foundationNavigation       ? $(this).foundationNavigation() : null;
    $.fn.foundationTopBar           ? $(this).foundationTopBar() : null;
    $.fn.foundationCustomForms      ? $(this).foundationCustomForms() : null;
    $.fn.foundationMediaQueryViewer ? $(this).foundationMediaQueryViewer() : null;
    $.fn.foundationTabs             ? $(this).foundationTabs({callback : $.foundation.customForms.appendCustomMarkup}) : null;
    $.fn.foundationTooltips         ? $(this).foundationTooltips() : null;
    $.fn.foundationMagellan         ? $(this).foundationMagellan() : null;
    $.fn.foundationClearing         ? $(this).foundationClearing() : null;
    $.fn.placeholder                ? $(this).find('input, textarea').placeholder() : null;
  };

  var $doc = $(document),
      Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $doc.foundation();
  });

  // UNCOMMENT THE LINE YOU WANT BELOW IF YOU WANT IE8 SUPPORT AND ARE USING .block-grids
  // $('.block-grid.two-up>li:nth-child(2n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.three-up>li:nth-child(3n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.four-up>li:nth-child(4n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});
  // $('.block-grid.five-up>li:nth-child(5n+1)').css({clear: 'both'});

  // Hide address bar on mobile devices (except if #hash present, so we don't mess up deep linking).
  if (Modernizr.touch && !window.location.hash) {
    $(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
      }, 0);
    });
  }

})(jQuery, this);
```

---

About RequireJS, it's necessary to include all the Foundation (ver 3.2.5) plugins file and not the minified one. So, my `main.js` looks like that:

```
require.config({
    paths:
    {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        'jquery-event-move': 'libs/foundation/jquery.event.move',
        'jquery-event-swipe': 'libs/foundation/jquery.event.swipe',
        'jquery-placeholder': 'libs/foundation/jquery.placeholder',
        'foundation-modernizr': 'libs/foundation/modernizr.foundation',
        'foundation-accordion': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.accordion',
        'foundation-alerts': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.alerts',
        'foundation-buttons': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.buttons',
        'foundation-clearing': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.clearing',
        'foundation-forms': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.forms',
        'foundation-joyride': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.joyride',
        'foundation-magellan': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.magellan',
        'foundation-media-query-toggle': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle',
        'foundation-navigation': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.navigation',
        'foundation-orbit': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.orbit',
        'foundation-reveal': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.reveal',
        'foundation-tabs': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.tabs',
        'foundation-tooltips': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.tooltips',
        'foundation-topbar': 'libs/foundation/jquery.foundation.topbar',
        'foundation-app': 'libs/foundation/app',
    },
    shim:
    {
        'underscore': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'models/User': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'environment'],
            exports: 'User'
        },
        'models/Token': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'environment'],
            exports: 'Token'
        },
        'jquery-event-move': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery-event-swipe': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery-placeholder': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-modernizer': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-accordion': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-alerts': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-buttons': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-clearing': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-forms': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-joyride': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-magellan': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-media-query-toggle': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-navigation': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-orbit': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-reveal': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-tabs': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-tooltips': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-topbar': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'foundation-app': {
            deps: [
                'jquery',
                'jquery-event-move',
                'jquery-event-swipe',
                'jquery-placeholder',
                'foundation-modernizr',
                'foundation-alerts',
                'foundation-buttons',
                'foundation-clearing',
                'foundation-forms',
                'foundation-joyride',
                'foundation-magellan',
                'foundation-media-query-toggle',
                'foundation-navigation',
                'foundation-orbit',
                'foundation-reveal',
                'foundation-tabs',
                'foundation-tooltips',
                'foundation-topbar',
            ]
        },
    }
});

// Requiring Foundation framework
require(['foundation-app']);

// Instantiating MVC
require([
    'app',
], function(App)
{
    App.initialize();
});
```

---

In the end, to make the Backbone views to render correctly with Foundation (at least with new DOM sections), I do like that:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'foundation-app'
], function($, _, Backbone)
{
    var FoundationView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        el: $('#view-placeholder'),

        initialize: function()
        {
            this.on('post-render', this.onPostRender, this);
        },

        render: function(content)
        {
            var content = 'new dom section';
            $(this.el).html(content);

            this.trigger('post-render');
        },

        onPostRender: function()
        {
            $(this.el).foundation();
        }
    });

    return FoundationView;
});
```